# How to write a streaming DataFrame out to Kafka with all rows as JSON array?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am looking for a solutions for the writing the spark streaming data to kafka.
I am using following method to write data to kafka

```
df.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value").writeStream.format("kafka")
```

But my issue is while writing to kafka the data showing as following

```
{"country":"US","plan":postpaid,"value":300}
{"country":"CAN","plan":0.0,"value":30}
```

my expected output is

```
   [
    {"country":"US","plan":postpaid,"value":300}
    {"country":"CAN","plan":0.0,"value":30}
   ]
```

I want enclose the rows inside the array. How can achieve the same in spark streaming ? can someone advice

Comment: By "expected output" you mean you need to have an array (multiline) in Kafka although you write one-line to Kafka? If that is what you expect - then maybe just write multiline to Kafka initially

Comment: i want an array (multiline) in Kafka ...whatever dataframe i write at a particular time should be enclosed in an array

Comment: Can you paste the output of `df.printSchema` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the schema of the streaming DataFrame (`df`) is as follows:

```
root
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- plan: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I also assume that you want to write (*produce*) all rows in the streaming DataFrame (`df`) out to a Kafka topic as a single record in which the rows are in the form of an array of JSONs.

If so, you should `groupBy` the rows and `collect_list` to group all rows into one that you could write out to Kafka.

```
// df is a batch DataFrame so I could show for demo purposes
scala> df.show
+-------+--------+-----+
|country|    plan|value|
+-------+--------+-----+
|     US|postpaid|  300|
|    CAN|     0.0|   30|
+-------+--------+-----+

val jsons = df.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
scala> jsons.show(truncate = false)
+------------------------------------------------+
|value                                           |
+------------------------------------------------+
|{"country":"US","plan":"postpaid","value":"300"}|
|{"country":"CAN","plan":"0.0","value":"30"}     |
+------------------------------------------------+

val grouped = jsons.groupBy().agg(collect_list("value") as "value")
scala> grouped.show(truncate = false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"country":"US","plan":"postpaid","value":"300"}, {"country":"CAN","plan":"0.0","value":"30"}]|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd do all the above in [DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter) to get ahold of a DataFrame to work on.

Comment: I can accept the answer ...but the issue is i am already using one group by operation to generate the final data frame..i cant apply group by operation again since am using structured streaming API(not support for multilevel aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if that is achievable, but I'll post my suggestion anyway here; so what you can do is transform your Dataframe afterwards:

```
 //Input  
 inputDF.show(false)
 +---+-------+
 |int|string |
 +---+-------+
 |1  |string1|
 |2  |string2|
 +---+-------+

 //convert that to json
 inputDF.toJSON.show(false)
 +----------------------------+
 |value                       |
 +----------------------------+
 |{"int":1,"string":"string1"}|
 |{"int":2,"string":"string2"}|
 +----------------------------+

 //then use collect and mkString
 println(inputDF.toJSON.collect().mkString("[", "," , "]"))
 [{"int":1,"string":"string1"},{"int":2,"string":"string2"}]
```

Comment: collect() operation doesn't work in spark structured streaming